# Implementing Composite Keys in CodeIgniter Models

Tags: codeigniter, composite-primary-key, codeigniter-4

Is there any way you could implement composite primary keys using `Models` in CodeIgniter 4?

Like this?

```
class SomeModel extends Model{
   
   protected $table      = 'table';
   protected $primaryKey1 = 'primary_composite_id1';
   protected $primaryKey2 = 'primary_composite_id2';
   protected $primaryKey3 = 'primary_composite_id3';

   // numbers in the identifiers were only added for clarity
   ...

}
```

I think you can define the table structure using the `Forge` class. 
Here is a snippet of how I defined the table in Migrations.

in `SomeMigration.php`

```
class SomeClass extends Migration{

    /* added fields here */
    ...
    
    // Set them as foreign keys
    $this->$forge->addForeignKey('item_id', 'item', 'item_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
    $this->$forge->addForeignKey('poster_uid', 'user', 'user_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
    $this->$forge->addForeignKey('customer_uid', 'user', 'user_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');


    // Set them as primary keys
    $this->$forge->addPrimaryKey('item_id');
    $this->$forge->addPrimaryKey('poster_uid');
    $this->$forge->addPrimaryKey('customer_uid');
    
    ...
}
```

Also, if setting composite primary keys in `Models` are not possible, should I

- Create a new primary key column for that table instead?
- Leave out the `$primarykey` value as empty and use just use queries (e.g. using `WHERE`)?
- Use any one of the columns(set as PK) in the table as the value for `$primarykey`?

*questions were created based on this post [Codeigniter MY_Model composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062606/codeigniter-my-model-composite-primary-key), since the answer did not directly answer the question*

*I am currently using the framework for our school project. There was none mentioned in the documentation, so I got stuck. Any kind of alternative solution is very much appreciated. Thanks! Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem these days.
It seems that Codeigniter doesn't support this functionality for the model's primary key.

I searched in documentation and in Model's source code and I saw that it handles the primary key like one value.
e.g. at models find method I can see this code:

`$row = $builder->whereIn($this->table . '.' . $this->primaryKey, $id)`

In my case I will add an extra ID column and use this as a primary key. If I find a better alternative in the future I will update here.

Best Regards